# For loops and an array, trouble ouputting dynamically created divs

Tags: php, loops, math

I have trouble outputting some queried data which is stored in an array that I want to show in html like this:

ID1/NewsTitle1/NewsDate1

ID2/NewsTitle2/NewsDate2

ID3/NewsTitle3/NewsDate3

ID4/NewsTitle4/NewsDate4

Yet it is showing like this:

ID1/NewsTitle1/NewsDate1

ID1/NewsTitle1/NewsDate1

ID1/NewsTitle1/NewsDate1

ID1/NewsTitle1/NewsDate1

Some extra info:
$this->_count_colls = 3;
$this->_count_keys = 4;

The PHP code:

```
public function __construct($sent_query_result)
{
    $this->_sent_query_result = $sent_query_result;
    $this->_count_colls = $this->_sent_query_result['count_colls'];
    $this->_count_keys = count($this->_sent_query_result) - 1;
    print_r($this->_count_keys);

    for($i = 0; $i <= $this->_count_keys - 1; $i++) {
        echo '<div class="tr">';
            for($j = 0; $j <= $this->_count_colls - 1; $j++) {
                echo '<div class="td">' . $this->_sent_query_result[0][$j] . '</div>';
            }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

The 0 in the following line has to be incremented by 3 it seems yet I can't get this to work by replacing it with $j or $j++.

```
$this->_sent_query_result[0][$j]
```

Edit:

The array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => 1752 [1] => Test1 [2] => 2011-07-05 15:26:38 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => 1753 [1] => Test2 [2] => 2011-07-05 15:26:41 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => 1754 [1] => Test3 [2] => 2011-07-05 15:26:47 ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => 1755 [1] => Test4 [2] => 2011-07-05 15:26:51 ) 
)
```

Comment: Can you post the array also? It may help.

Comment: Have you tried: `$this->_sent_query_result[$i][$j]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$j` is the column key what you need is the result key `$i`.

Try changing this:

```
$this->_sent_query_result[0][$j]
```

to this:

```
$this->_sent_query_result[$i][$j]
```

Comment: Goodness me I really thought I had tried that already. Thanks!